# Index page does not show the object of db or sometime it shows undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to build a shopping cart but it doesn't show what the cart contains.

Something is wrong here is my code in the controller and blade:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $id = Auth::id();

        $results = DB::table('carts')
                        ->select('book_id')
                        ->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                        ->get();

        $data = (array) $results;

        $books = Book::all()->whereIn('id', $data);

        return view('carts.index')->withBooks($books);
    }
```

```
    @foreach($books as $book)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $book->autori }} </td>
            <td> {{ $book->titulli }} </td>
            <td> {{ $book->cmimi }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: btw, instead of doing this $data = (array)$results; you could also do $data = $results->toArray();

To your problem, 
This is not the right way:
            $books=Book::all()->whereIn('id', $data );
instead, do this: $books = Book::whereIn('id', $data)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
     $booksIds = DB::table('carts')
         ->select('book_id')
         ->where('user_id','=', Auth::id())
         ->get()
         ->pluck('book_id')
         ->toArray();

     $books = Book::whereIn('id', $booksIds)->get();

     return view('carts.index')->withBooks($books);
}
```

or using a single query:

```
public function index()
{
     $books = Book::join('carts', static function($join) {
          $join->on('books.id', '=', 'carts.book_id')
               ->where('carts.user_id', '=', Auth::id());
     })->get();

     return view('carts.index')->withBooks($books);
}
```

You should read about and use [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: I think the first line can be reduced to this: `DB::table('carts')->where('user_id','=', Auth::id())->pluck('book_id');` It will return a collection and `whereIn` accept collection, so it's fine. But using a single query is probably better anyway.